# Absolute reverse routing with Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, url-routing, playframework-2.0

In play 1.X it was possible to have an absolute url with reverse routing using :

```
@@{MyController.method(param)} --> http://www.mydomain.com/myaction/param
```

instead of relative reverse routing with :

```
@{MyController.method(param)} --> /myaction/param
```

I use play 2.0 with scala version. I can retrieve relative routes using :

```
@routes.MyController.method(param) --> /myaction/param
```

As "@@" just escapes the "@" reserved for scala statements, is it still possible to have also absolute reverse routing ? I can't find it in the API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `absoluteUrl` method to retrieve the absolute address.

So :

```
@routes.MyController.method(param).absoluteURL()
```